# PHP Mysql login page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Im still new at php and I am trying to make a login page. I am having trouble redirecting people back to my login page if they have not logged in yet. I don't want anybody to have direct access to my index page through the url.

So far on top of my index page I have

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["userid"])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Should I also have a session_start() on top of my login page? When a person logs I have this function

```
function loginUser($conn, $username, $password) {
    $usernameExists = usernameExists($conn, $username, $username);

    if($usernameExists === false) {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=wronglogin");
        exit();
    }

    $passwordHashed = $usernameExists["userPassword"];
    $checkPassword = password_verify($password, $passwordHashed);

    if($checkPassword === false) {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=wronglogin");
        exit();
    }
    else if ($checkPassword === true) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $usernameExists["userId"];
        $_SESSION["userName"] = $usernameExists["username"];
        header("location: ../index.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

But so far every time I login with it does not let me go to my index page anymore unless I only have session_start() on top of my index page. But once i put

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["userid"])) {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
```

it does not let me go to the index page anymore. When I log in it just takes me back to the login page again.

Comment: Don't forget to `exit;` after sending a `Location` header.

Comment: "Should I also have a session_start() on top of my login page?" Yes, if you want to use the $_SESSION variable you need to call session_start()

Comment: But you should not check `isset($_SESSION["userid"])` at the top of the login page, because the person who is seeing your login page is not logged on at that time.